# HTML form with a PHP variable test

Tags: php, variables, captcha

I'm trying to add some very simple PHP CAPTCHA code to my existing HTML web forms, using my same server side php form mailer.

Example form with simple CAPTCHA:

```
<?
session_start();
?>
<html>
Number challange test<br />
<br />
</html>
<body>
<?
// check login - only code
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
     echo "running code comparison now  ";
    if ($_SESSION['captcha']==$_REQUEST['code']) echo 'login ok';
    else echo 'login failed';
}
else {
?>
<form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br />
Password: <input type="text" name="password" /><br />
<img src="example.php" />
Code: <input type="text" name="code" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />

</form>
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My specific question is, how can I modify the above form concept to submit my form data to my server-side form_mailer.php, (Not submit to itself) and also validate the 'captcha' value to = the '`code`'?

I have tried to read/display the value of the `$_SESSION['captcha']` (its a 4 digit number) but nothing I do with Echo displays the value.  I think if I (could read/display) this value I could validate the code on the fly.

I'm testing the use of a Validate button separate from the Submit button.  This is what i'm trying to accomplish with one Submit button.

Example.php code:

```
<?
session_start();

include('captcha_numbers.php');
$captcha = new CaptchaNumbers(4);
$captcha -> display();

$_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha -> getString();
?>
```

Source: [Source of all code for this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2598-PHP-Generate-CAPTCHA-validation-images.html)

Answer (score 0):

Insted of

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
```

use

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Becouse you are using a POST method in your form.

We don’t know your code. Your captcha code can be generated every time someone starts the session and its different then. Try something else.
For captcha there’s a simple trick like placing a hidden md5.
https://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.md5.php
or something stronger like sha1
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

```
<input type="hidden" name="captcha_md5" value="<?php echo md5($my_number); ?>"/>
```

After that make a md5 out of the code someone gives in the form and compare it.

```
if ($_POST['captcha_md5']==md5($_POST['code'])) echo 'login ok';
```

Captcha gives a different number every time, and md5 generates a shortcut that's not possible to revers. :)
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

check the "example.php" code,see if it saves the number into $_SESSION['captcha']

try to write some text log in "example.php" ,and dont forget the session_start() in "example.php"